# Nginx and Iis on port 80

Tags: node.js, nginx, iis

Little background....

We are already using IIS server 7.5  for our .Net web applications. Now we are developing WEB API in nodejs and wants to deploy the same on the existing Production infra.

Is is possible to use port 80 for both IIS and Nginx?

One of the possible solution I think will work is to have two public IPs configured on the LIVE infra and ask each server ie IIS and Nginx(nginx as  proxy for node app) to listen to port  80  for http and 443 for https of respective public IP.

Note : I do not wish to use IIS url rewrite to forward request from IIS to nginx or vice versa.

Would appreciate if you guys can point me to right direction

Thanks

Comment: No, you can't have two applications listening on the same IP and Port. You can have the same port on multiple interfaces.

Comment: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingAndRunningNodejsApplicationsWithinIISOnWindowsAreYouMad.aspx

Comment: Diff IP and same port ?